# Enviar variable de GS a segundo HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Particularmente tengo un GSheet con tablas de valores, los cuales capturo en la secuencia de comandos. Cuento con un index.html y un prueba.html (se llega aqui desde el index). En prueba.html, deseo mostrar los valores obtenidos en la secuencia de comandos (GS), pero no estoy pudiendo hacerlo, si los puedo mostrar en index. Me dan una mano con algunos ejemplos?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investiado como se sugiere en [ask].

Comment: Sin saber el código que has hecho es complicado encontrar el problema, pero si quieres ejemplos aquí te puedo dejar unos cuantos:
  [1]: https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2015/02/como-crear-una-web-con-google-apps.html
  [2]: https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2015/03/como-crear-una-web-dinamica-con-google.html
  [3]: https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2015/12/como-hacer-un-web-login-con-google-apps.html

Comment: [4]: https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2017/07/como-leer-parametros-de-la-url-con.html
  [5]: https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2020/07/como-poner-en-un-iframe-una-web-hecha-con-gas.html
  [6]: https://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com/2020/08/como-usar-templates-web-con-google-apps.html

Comment: con .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)   Donde onSuccess es la function que recibe la data del Servidor.   Este link te puede ayudar https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction